# ROS navigation slam example

Tags: slam, navigation, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Is there any navigation slam example(c,c++) with hokuyo node (only usb port,no serial port),
with rviz(show map,and setting goal),map(not static map)?

If it also includes gazebo and pictures(laser range finder location,robot),tutorials will be great~

If it totally follows the navigation tutorials will be the best!

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10190/ros-navigation-slam-example/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a look at this http://www.hessmer.org/blog/2011/04/24/using-the-ros-navigation-stack/ for a real robot to look at that was set up using the navigation stack.  I have also got the Navigation stack working with the hokuyo_node and the SLAM package as well if you need more information Ill post more here like .launch files and the such.  Dr. Hessmer's Blog is useful for understanding the navigation package as well as he provides all of his code, just make sure to check out the right revision. If you are not using an arduino then you will have to change how you get your odometery and tf for the odom, but other than that its pretty straight forward. I also had issues looking at the tutorials and doing the Nav stack, and this helped a lot.  It does not however integrate gazebo. It does follow the navigation tutorials very well though.

Enjoy,
-Drew

---

Originally posted by [D_mangus](https://answers.ros.org/users/617/d_mangus/) with karma: 121 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2